# Populate drop down options - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im using javascript to populate options for my select and cant understand what Is going wrong.
I am trying to input dates into a select option, but it is only adding 2003-2004.

Here is my javascript function:

```
function populateDropDown(previousYear, currentYear) {
    console.log(previousYear)
    console.log(currentYear)
    var prevYear
    var curYear
    var i
    var y = document.getElementById("membershipYear");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    for(i = 1;i <= 10;i++) {
        prevYear = previousYear - i
        curYear = currentYear - i
        console.log(prevYear + "-" + curYear)
        option.text = prevYear + "-" + curYear
        y.add(option,y[i])
    }
}
```

and printing in my console log is this:

```
2012-2013
2011-2012
2010-2011
2009-2010
2008-2009
2007-2008
2006-2007
2005-2006
2004-2005
2003-2004
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move createElement into the loop like this:

```
function populateDropDown(previousYear, currentYear) {
console.log(previousYear)
console.log(currentYear)
var prevYear
var curYear
var i
var y = document.getElementById("membershipYear");

for(i = 1;i <= 10;i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
prevYear = previousYear - i
curYear = currentYear - i
console.log(prevYear + "-" + curYear)
option.text = prevYear + "-" + curYear
y.add(option,y[i])
}
}
```

Comment: That worked! Didn't even think about creating the option every time within the loop. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create option element each time then add in your Dropdown otherwise opetion will be overwrite everytime.

keep `var option = document.createElement("option");` into for loop so every it will create new option.